# [eclipse]an error occurred while accessing the repository entry

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit, javahl

the eclipse shows these errors.

[image]

i've areadly download the svn,and svnkit
[image]

Comment: yes ,seems there is another plugin have to install

Comment: Which plugin you have to install?

Comment: which plugin to install?

Answer (score 0):

Check for `Window`->`Preferences`->`Team`->`SVN`->`SVN Connector`. If not install it

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse supports Subversion via plug-ins: [Subversive](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) (the one you had installed according to the screenshot in your question) and [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse). Your question does not show real errors, so I do not know what was actually going on with Subversive. However, consider the following suggestions:

- Try switching the SVN Connector to Native JavaHL.
- Try Replacing Subversive with Subclipse and see whether you receive the same errors.

Note that the [following article](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00145/) provides step by step instructions to enable Native JavaHL SVN Connector for Subversive and Subclipse both.